# How to get a navigation bar hight in iOS programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar

I have to move up my view when `keyboardwillshown` then it back to it's normal place when keyboard will hide

Actually I have used this code on `viewdidload` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() { 

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil) 

}
```

Here is the method which I used for move up and down

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification){ 

    print("keyboardwillshow")
    let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue()

    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, -keyboardSize!.size.height + (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height)! + 20 , self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height )  

}

func keyboardWillHide(notification:NSNotification){

    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height)!, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
//  self.view.frame.origin.y += 350

}
```

While I run this program, it will show a run time error that is

> unexpected found a nil while unwrapping

Please help me fix this.

Comment: The problem here is the nil unwrapping exception, which is most likely caused by the statement `(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height)!`. It suggests that some part of that expression is not initialised — are you sure that your view controller is inside a navigation controller? What happens if you put a breakpoint there and check the value of `self.navigationController`, by typing `po self.navigationController` into the debug console?

Answer (score 9):

With iPhone-X, height of top bar (navigation bar + status bar) is changed (increased).

Try this if you want exact height of top bar (both navigation bar + status bar):

**Objective-C**

```
CGFloat topbarHeight = ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height +
       (self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height ?: 0.0));
```

**Swift 4**

```
let topBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height +
        (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0.0)
```

For ease, try this UIViewController extension

```
extension UIViewController {

    /**
     *  Height of status bar + navigation bar (if navigation bar exist)
     */

    var topbarHeight: CGFloat {
        return UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height +
            (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0.0)
    }
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
let topBarHeight = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height +
(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

In **Swift 3** You will get the navigation bar height by using the following way:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.intrinsicContentSize.height
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let navigationBarHeight = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0
```

Comment: I would do it slightly differently: 

`let navigationBarHeight = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0`

Answer (score 0):

You should protect your code against nil values this way. it will also help in using your view controllers inside navigation controllers and outside.

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification){

    print("keyboardwillshow")
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        if let navBarHeight = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height {
            self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, -keyboardSize.size.height + navBarHeight + 20 , self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height )
        } else {
            print("could not get navbar height")
            self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, -keyboardSize.size.height + 20 , self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height )
        }
    } else {
        print("no keyboard size property")
    }

}
```